# past perfect tense usage -- I had called you yesterday before leaving

Tags: past-tense, usage, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

Is the sentence below correct?

> I **had called** you yesterday before leaving.

Comment: yes it is. Why makes you be unsure? You could also say: "I had called you yesterday before I left."

Comment: It is certainly a valid sentence. Without knowing how you intend to use it, it's  impossible to say whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

> I had called you yesterday before leaving.

The sentence above is correct grammatically. What really matters is how you use it. If it's a call by mobile phone(or any other device), it's better to use the phrase 'rang you up' in the UK. Like this:

> I rang you up yesterday before leaving.

The phrase 'call on someone' has also got a meaning 'to visit someone'. Though, it's an old usage it can still confuse people. So it's better that you use it according to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatical, and you can say, it, but people probably wouldn't in most cases.

It is sometimes said that you use the past perfect whenever you are referring to something before another event. This is an oversimplification.

You use the past perfect when you are choosing to look back from a later time: it is almost always a choice that the speaker makes, if they want to put the temporal focus at a later point.

You would say *I had called you yesterday before leaving* only if the temporal focus is at the time of leaving (probably you are then going on to talk more about your leaving, or what you did afterwards). If there is no particular focus (for example, if it is an isolated statement) you probably wouldn't use *had*.

Also, English speakers often don't use it even when there is a temporal focus, if the temporal relationships are obvious (which they are here, because of the "before").